# How to add identity column to datatable using c#

Tags: c#

How to add identity column to datatable using c#. Im using Sql compact server.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could try something like this maybe?

```
private void AddAutoIncrementColumn()
{
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    column.AutoIncrement = true;
    column.AutoIncrementSeed = 1000;
    column.AutoIncrementStep = 10;

    // Add the column to a new DataTable.
    DataTable table = new DataTable("table");
    table.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

Comment: When added to an existing DataTable with data in it, will this automatically populate the new column in the existing rows?

Comment: One line version:
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)) { AutoIncrement = true, AutoIncrementSeed = 1, AutoIncrementStep = 1 });

Answer (score 7):

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable("table");


DataColumn dc= table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        dc.AutoIncrement=true;
        dc.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        dc.AutoIncrementStep = 1;

// Add the new column name in DataTable

table.Columns.Add("name",typeof(string));

    table.Rows.Add(null, "A");
    table.Rows.Add(null, "B");
    table.Rows.Add(null, "C");
```

Answer (score 5):

If the DataTable is already populated. you can use below method

```
void AddAndPopulateDataTableRowID(DataTable dt, string col, bool isGUID)
    {
        if(isGUID)
            dt.Columns.Add(col, typeof(System.Guid));
        else
            dt.Columns.Add(col, typeof(System.Int32));

        int rowid = 1;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (isGUID)
                dr[col] = Guid.NewGuid();
            else
                dr[col] = rowid++;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't do autoincrement on DataTable (or front-end for that matter), unless you want to make your application a single user application only.

If you need the autoincrement, just do it in database, then retrieve the autoincremented id produced from database to your front-end.

See my answer here, just change the SqliteDataAdapter to SqlDataAdapter, SqliteConnection to SqlConnection, etc : [anyway see why I get this "Concurrency Violation" in these few lines of code??? Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599230/anyway-see-why-i-get-this-concurrency-violation-in-these-few-lines-of-code/1604547#1604547)

Comment: I'm reading data from flat file and need to add a line number to the DataTable - there are times when this is valid, and no it won't make my app single user.

Comment: yeah, or for output.....  I'm generating output which is made up of multiple, independent reads, which need to end up in a single sequence.  It's a very important local use of the DataTable......   similar isolation as "single-user", but not at all the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents. Auto-increment is useful in a `Winform` app (stand alone as Michael Buen rightly said), i.e.:

> `DatagridView` is being used to display data that does not have a "key field", the same can be used for enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its a good idea to use autoincrement on datatable if you are using insert and delete to a datatable because the number will not be rearranget, no final i will share a small idea how can we use autoincrement manual.

```
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID",typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Produto Nome", typeof(string));  

        dt.Rows.Add(null, "A");
        dt.Rows.Add(null, "B");
        dt.Rows.Add(null, "C");

        for(int i=0;i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[i]["ID"] = i + 1;
        }
```

always when finalizing the insert or delete must run this loop

```
         for(int i=0;i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[i]["ID"] = i + 1;
        }
```

Comment: This is really confusing. And changing `DataTable` doesn't change the DB, and I believe this is the essential part of OPs question.