# Auto assign a unique ID Number sequentially

Tags: c#

I am creating a dealer form using c#
In which I wanted unique dealer Id for each dealer
please help me how to auto assign a unique code to 
new member sequentially in the format

> D1,D2, D3, D4,..

I want to use disconnected enviorenment in ADO.net and 
i want to save that id in SQL server 2005

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xUi9c.jpg]

Comment: You might want to consider / look into using the SQL server identity feature.

Comment: DataTable with an identity field will do the trick, however, if this is a form being used by many users then you need a database approach. Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839168/how-to-add-identity-column-to-datatable-using-c-sharp

Comment: but i need alphanumeric auto increment using c#

Comment: please read my question carefully

Comment: i need help from u because this is my main project.Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate unique Ids disconnect from SQL Server and then save them into the database without conflicts you can use [SQL GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) and not integer. In C# for each new dealer you can generate a new GUID and then commit into database, using a [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) will let you work disconnected from SQL Server with unlimited number of clients.

Comment: But i didn't understand this concept SQL GUID