# Get row index in datatable from a certain column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+------------+
| A | B | C |
| D | E | F | 
| G | H | I |
```

---

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("1");
dt.Columns.Add("2");
dt.Columns.Add("3");
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A", "B", "C" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "D", "E", "F" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "G", "H", "I" });

int? index = null;

var rows = new System.Data.DataView(dt).ToTable(false, new[] {"1"}).Rows;

for (var i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (rows[i].ItemArray.FirstOrDefault() as string == "A")
        index = i;
}
```

Is there any way to simplify this code for fetching the index of a certain row, with a column provided? In this case, index will be `0`, since I'm iterating through the first column until i find "A". Feels like there should be a linq solution to this, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use the [DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) method, you will be able to query your DataTable with LINQ. You can then use [`List<T>.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx) to determine the index of a given predicate:

```
int? index = new System.Data.DataView(dt).ToTable(false, new[] { "1" })
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(row => row.Field<string>("1")) // ie. project the col(s) needed
                .ToList()
                .FindIndex(col => col == "G"); // returns 2
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) method like this:

```
DataRow[] foundRows;
string filter = "1 == A";
foundRows = dt.Select(filter);

foreach (DataRow dr in foundRows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Index is " + dr.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dr));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var index = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
            let r = row.Field<string>("1")
            where r == "A"
            select dt.Rows.IndexOf(row);
```

Comment: how do I use the index as an int then?

Comment: `IndexOf` returns an `int`.

Comment: still it is a var, changing it to an int gives error, using index as a var for a method that expects an int gives errors aswell :(

Comment: I'm assuming your problem was the fact that index was actually an `EnumerableRowCollection<int>`?  It's the callers responsibility to make sure you only have one record if that's what you're expecting and grab whatever value is in that record, in this case an `int`.

Comment: Sort of yes, could not convert from <int> to int, so I had to use foreach, even through it only contains one record for sure. Improvement tip? Can I just cast it or Parse it?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to an identity column. However, I do not know your application so please consider the pros and the cons of adding an identity column to your datatable. Here is a reference to get you started - [how to add identity column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839168/how-to-add-identity-column-to-datatable-using-c-sharp)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use linq operation, but for that your target framework should be 4.5.
Import system.Data.DataExtensions and apply the linq query will help you out.