# How to query DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a datatable like that:

```
column1 column2 column3
   a       b       c
   d       e       f
```

I want to get index numbers of the cell "e" and i wrote these

```
int[] indexrowcol = new int[2];
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[i][j] == "e")
        {
            indexrowcol[0] = j; indexrowcol[1] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

How to write the same thing with usin LINQ? thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get row index in datatable from a certain column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952660/get-row-index-in-datatable-from-a-certain-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you have your original code implemented correctly to get what you're after.  But at least it's more or less clear what you're trying to do.  Here's some commented link code that can accomplish it.

```
var valToSearch = "e";

int[] indexrowcol = dt.AsEnumerable() // allows you to use linq
    .SelectMany((row,rix) => // like 'Select', but stacks up listed output
        row.ItemArray.Select( // ItemArray gets the row as an array
            (col,cix) => new { rix, cix, value = col.ToString() }
        )
    )
    .Where(obj => obj.value == valToSearch)
    .Select(obj => new int[] { obj.rix, obj.cix })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

---

When I use the above code on the following DataTable, I get the result `[1,1]`, which is the same result I get using your original code when I correct for the i/j reversal that existed at the time of this writing.

```
var dt = new DataTable(); 
dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
dt.Columns.Add("Column3");

DataRow rw = dt.NewRow();
rw["Column1"] = "a";
rw["Column2"] = "b";
rw["Column3"] = "c";
dt.Rows.Add(rw);

rw = dt.NewRow();
rw["Column1"] = "d";
rw["Column2"] = "e";
rw["Column3"] = "f";
dt.Rows.Add(rw);
```

---

The reason your original code isn't quite right is that you use 'i' for columns and 'j' for rows, but then call `dt.Rows[i][j]`, which is backwards.  I highly recommend that your variables can be matched to what they are associated with.  This is why I use names such as `col`, `row`, `cix` (column index), and `rix` to keep things straight.

In that vein, you might want to also output something other than an int[2].  Maybe a class or struct, or even just leave it as an anonymous object (get rid of the 'select' part of my query).  Though I don't know your end use case, so I'll leave you alone on that.